# Replaced fragment is always displayed - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with five tabs.
I want to replace fragment when a button is clicked.

```
public class TimelineFragment extends RootFragment {

    public TimelineFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_timeline, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AccountFragment accountFragment = new AccountFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Store the Fragment in stack
                transaction.replace(R.id.container_pager, accountFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Problem : when the button is clicked, we can see the new fragment with a textview, but the button of the older fragment is always displayed.
Why ?

I follow this tutorial : https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/

Comment: Probably the problem is in the FragmentMaganer you are using `getChildFragmentManager` but should use normal not child

Comment: If I use getFragmentManager, there is the same problem and the backstack doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View 
                FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ft.beginTransaction()

                        .replace(R.id.container_pager, new accountFragment())
                        .addToBackStack("Back")
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I can't call getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: I tried to call getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() but there is the same problem.